AWS SQS Messages available lesser than what I sent
I'm not sure if I understand the concept wrong or AWS SQS itself is not a reliable service.
I send 1000 messages into the FIFO queue from my website sitting in AWS Amplify. Checking the AWS CloudWatch, the Amplify server shows all 1000 loop is been recorded.
But in my SQS dashboard, the queue Message available only 69. The next day, it is still 69 and when I purge them, the number remains 0. So, what happen to the remaining 931?
In future, I'm planning to send the messages to lambda so it can blast to AWS SES, but seeing even the SQS not receiving all 1000 messages, how can it be reliable.
Below is my code to send it :-
import { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const sqs = new SQSClient({
  region: env.SES_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: env.SES_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: env.SES_SECRET_KEY,
  },
});

const sqsMessageGroupId = `${Date.now()}`;
      for (let x = 0; x < input.toAddress.length; x++) {
        console.log(
          `sending emails ${x + 1} of ${input.toAddress.length}. Email subject is ${input.subject}`,
        );

        const sqsCommand = new SendMessageCommand({
          QueueUrl: env.SQS_QUEUE_URL,
          MessageBody: JSON.stringify({
            to: [input.toAddress[x]!.emailAddress],
            subject: input.subject,
            html: input.bodyHtml,
            text: input.bodyPlainText,
          }),
          MessageGroupId: sqsMessageGroupId,
          MessageDeduplicationId: `${Date.now()}-${x}`,
        });
        sqs.send(sqsCommand).catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
          throw err;
        });
      }


Amazon SQS is a highly-scalable service spread across multiple data centers in each REgion that has been running for 20 years. Yes, it is reliable. Is there a particular reason why you are using the same sqsMessageGroupId for every message? That might be stopping you from receiving new messages since they need to be processed in-order.
